# Освобождение файла от программы

Tags: c#, mp3

Есть вот такой вот код:

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    _type q = get_type(e.FullPath);
    if (q.type1 == "audio")
    {
        var mp3File = TagLib.File.Create(e.FullPath);
        string artist = String.Join(", ", mp3File.Tag.Performers);
        string title = mp3File.Tag.Title;
        string src2 = folder_dir + @"/" + artist + " - " + title + ".mp3";
        System.IO.File.Move(e.FullPath, src2);
    }
    get_files_images_upload();
}
```

Код при создании, копировании и т.д аудиофайла в папку, переименовует его согласно его ID3 тегам. Но возникла проблема.

Строчка

```
var mp3File = TagLib.File.Create(e.FullPath);
```

вызывает IOException - файл используется другим процессом, но по сути файл только я использую

Comment: Покажите, что делает метод get_type()

Comment: дело не в get_type. get_type просто показывает что за файл. audio, image etc. Еще я заметил что ошибка выскакивает на второй раз. Тоесть один файл он обрабатывает нормально, а вот второй раз уже ругается

Comment: Тогда смотрите в get_files_images_upload()

Comment: Оно не играет роли сейчас. я его закоментировал и все так же.

Comment: Дело в потоках и системвотчере.

Comment: Если дело не в `get_type`, зачем он в вашем примере? Приведите, пожалуйста, **минимальный** (это значит, без UI) полный пример, воспроизводящий проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Событие Created возникает в тот момент, когда файл только-только появился на диске. Одновременно с попыткой его прочитать (ну или что вы делаете в `TagLib.File.Create`) его записывает та программа, которая его создала (вероятно, это Проводник или браузер).

Всё, что вам нужно в этой ситуации - это немного подождать и попытаться прочитать файл ещё раз.

Answer (score -1):

для упрощения контроля над ресурсами (откуда ноги растут) используйте общие значения

```
  //обьявите
  var tmpFile;


  if (tmpFile != null) { tmpFile.Dispose(); tmpFile= null; }
  tmpFile  = e.FullPath;
  e.FullPath.Dispose(); e.FullPath= null;
```

Comment: `var tmpFile;` не скомпилируется